# Make xslt 2.0 document a xslt 1.0 document

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm getting xslt 2.0 formed responses from a google search appliance and working with .net 3.5 I want to change these to xslt 1.0 documents. The reason is that the XSLCompileTransform crash working with the updated xslt document.

What are the attributes and such I would change to acheve this?

Cant post code since owner is government. 
//Edit:Why are people downwoting this question? At least leve a comment then. I really CANT leave more information, and got the answer I was looking for.

Comment: would help if you posted a copy of the xslt, there are various differences between versions.

Comment: You cannot simply use "attributes and such" to change XSLT 2.0 to XSLT 1.0. 2.0 has a large set of features that are not present in 1.0, so you would need t manually change the 2.0-only portions to 1.0 compatible logic.

Comment: @Treemonkey Not allowed to. Government secrets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are XSLT 2.0 processors that should work with .NET 3.5, such as the .NET version of [Saxon 9](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.4HE), [AltovaXML](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html) (only via COM interop), and [XmlPrime](http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/index.htm). Using one of them you should be able to run XSLT 2.0 stylesheets with .NET 3.5.

If you want to change the XSLT 2.0 code to run with an XSLT 1.0 processor like XslCompiledTransform then I agree with the suggestions made in the comments, you would need to check the code or show it to us to allow us to check it for XSLT 2.0 only features. The article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/10/09/xslt-1-0-biggest-issues-kind-of-solved.aspx could help.

The only simple and quick change is to change the `version="2.0"` attribute on `xsl:stylesheet` respectively `xsl:transform` to say `version="1.0"` but that way of course an XSLT 1.0 processor with continue to reject the stylesheet code if it uses XSLT 2.0 features like `for-each-group`.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. This is a government job and I'm not allowed to post any code or property of owner.